# How to make spring create a column with AUTO_INCREMENT?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, flyway

I'm using spring boot and created a table with a field like this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;
```

But the actual table created is

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name character varying(255),
    last_name character varying(255),
    password character varying(255),
    username character varying(255) UNIQUE
);
```

So the id column does not have the AUTO_INCREMENT property.

So the problem arise when I try to run sql myself, say to seed test data (using flyway) if I do

```
   INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password) VALUES ('admin', 'admin', 'admin', 'password') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

it will fail. Unless there is a way to run sql on column that does not have the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword?

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` it is missing to put `strategy`

Comment: I tried all the generation type,  one of them makes it auto increment. I think the increment logic is done in java itself